# Button increase font size / button decrease font size in Webview

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, font-size

How can i add to my application two buttons to increase / decrease font size of a HTML content in Webview control for Windows store app.
            **I'm designing Windows 8 Reader app, i.e.,display HTML content in "Webview". How to, increase the font in the HTML content in Webview when i click a button,decrease the font in the HTML content in Webview when i click another button**. I tried a lot for this.
          I need button click event code.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this using C# for Windows Store apps. Why it is there is no specific Control to increase or decrease the font in Webview control By Microsoft. You have to integrate with Java Script.

I recommend to go through Microsoft blogs & samples. [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) it is one of the samlpe for Windows Store apps.